# jquery each() function's proper usage

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery `each()` function but i think there is something wrong.
Here is the html and jquery code.

```
<div class="tribute">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="links"></div>
</div>

<div class="tribute odd">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="links"></div>
</div>

<div class="tribute">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="links"></div>
</div>

<div class="tribute odd">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="links"></div>
</div>

<div class="tribute">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="links"></div>
</div>

<div class="tribute odd">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="links"></div>
</div>
```

and jquery function

```
   jQuery('.odd').each(function(index, value){

     var oddLinks = jQuery('.odd').find('.links').detach();
     jQuery('.odd .image').before(oddLinks);

    });
```

this code is not properly working for me.

Comment: What do you expect and what is not working?

Comment: i want detach() .links div and append before .image only for odd wrapper.

Comment: The `.each()` method runs a loop through the matched elements, in this case it is all the `<div>`s with `.odd`. I don't see you using `index` or `value`, `value` refers to the singular matched element. Why are you doing `$('.odd')` again inside the `.each()` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean change the position of image and link in `.odd` div?
If so, you even don't need to detach it.

***[See the live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/kbQVP/)***

```
$('.odd').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.image').before($(this).find('.links'));
});
```

Comment: yes!
i want detach() .links div and append before .image only for odd wrapper.

Comment: before() function is also detach elements ?

Comment: @Furqan The element is still in the dom tree, so it's not necessary to detach it from the dom tree.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the context of the current `.odd` when iterating:

```
jQuery('.odd').each(function(index, value) {
    var oddLinks = jQuery(this).find('.links').detach();
    jQuery('.image', this).before(oddLinks);
});
```

`.odd` selects all `.odd` elements on the page.